# What is "wordface"?

Tags: meaning

I found this word in Terry Pratchett's Going Postal, and I can't find a definition for it anywhere. Any help?

> A few feet beyond there was the familiar wall of letters, packed as tight as rock strata. A watchman had been in here, too. Someone had tried to break through the **wordface**, and Moist could see the hole.

Thanks.

Comment: It would seem you can figure out what it means from the context.  There's a facing on the wall of letters.  Someone had cracked through some of the letters, or tried to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a neologism based on the term [rock face](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/rock_face).

> A bare vertical surface of natural rock.

But because this surface is composed of tightly packed letters written on paper, Pratchett chooses to call it a *wordface.*

Comment: Perhaps the intended analogy is more specific, *coalface* (the part of a mine that's currently being cut).

Answer (score 6):

Pterry is coining a neologism, making up the term "wordface" by analogy to "cliff-face." (Note the "rock strata" analogy.) He's just playing with the language.

(Later: Ah, missed it by *that* much!)